# ITMS-90427: Invalid Swift Support

Tags: ios, reactjs, native

ITMS-90427: Invalid Swift Support - The expected dylibs are missing from the app’s Framework location, such as /Payload/ProjectIos.app/Frameworks.

when i uppload my file in testflight i am facing this error on email by apple

ITMS-90427: Invalid Swift Support - The expected dylibs are missing from the app’s Framework location, such as /Payload/ProjectIos.app/Frameworks.

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: any luck on this @FahadBilal ?